# Is there any way to use JavaScript to replace text before or as the CRM/CMS sends out an email?

Tags: javascript

I have this text that I have to find "Buy this product" and I need to replace it with the french translation. Unfortunately jQuery isn't an option so I have to use JavaScript. The text sits in likely a td within a nameless table (im fairly certain as that is very common within this CRM/CMS system).

I've seen some examples like:

```
    function replace() {
        var matches = document.querySelectorAll("td");
        for(var index in matches) {
            if (matches[index].textContent === "Hello") {
                matches[index].textContent = "Hi";
            }
        }
    }
```

by: Xiao Ling (from another site)

Which to me looks like it should work however the main problem I'm having is getting the JavaScript to run in [some] email clients? I know most if not all will probably disable JS for security reasons but I was curious if there was a way to make this work?

background: The system was built to support English only, we paid to get French added however it wasn't added to all components like the upsell so right now our clients who have registered with the French locale will receive an email that is mostly in French with some elements showing up in English and I personally think that is bad practice so I'm hoping to fix it without having to pay even more money to the vendor to find a workaround.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You won't have much luck using JavaScript in an email. The changes need to be made at the source of whatever is generating the French version of the email. It sounds more like your problem is the vendor didn't do a complete job and they should be fixing their errors without extra pay.

Comment: Is it a fully custom CRM or are there docs we can look at?

Comment: @Herohtar thanks for reply! I thought as much, but figured I'd ask anyway just incase haha

Comment: @Shilly hi there, I'm not sure if you'll be able to access it: https://www.blackbaud.com/files/support/helpfiles/luminate-online/help/luminateonline.html   but this company is known for not updating their help doc in order to make $ from their support line. Unfortunately the business is far too invested in this tool to move to another one as I had suggested to them. I so far couldn't find anything in the doc, they use a lot of custom "S" and "E" tags my guess is PHP to do on the fly edits for a variety of things.

Comment: If there's an intermediate step between creating the content for the email and sending the email, you could intercept that function/call and reroute the content through some translator before sending it back to whatever emails it. But that does require access to the code and such.

Comment: oh that's a great idea, I'll see if something like that exists, might as well put their support to some sort of use lol

Comment: If you **paid** to get French added, and it was only added some places, then you should definitely go back and tell them. Be firm, as you already paid for it and are only getting a chunk of what you paid for..

Comment: Hmm, maybe you could create a different email campaign for english and french so you can use seperate email templates. ( Or different email express or quickmail, depending on which one you use )

Comment: @Shilly sorry I should have provided more info. When a person registers they can in English or French the components that get embedded into the email most of it is in French except for this one "upsell" feature that for some reason doesn't support another language.

Comment: @Jimenemex you're right. I had brought that up Blackbaud said that original company of this CRM didn't have a multi-language feature supported at all and so "over the years BB has been upgrading components focusing on priority ones" I argued but the bosses are the ones who settled so my hands are tied. The worst part is about 60% of constituent data isn't stored as database objects...they're stored in some sort of text file so migrating to another database is going to be painful. No one knew until I investigated, 9 years this company been using this system and previous devs never checked...

Comment: Alas you seem to be in a catch22 then. Any solution including javascript translation or editting those text files or the database will be a big bad practice. So if the system is that important, I would not touch it. Any unforeseen consequence of messing with it might cost the wrong person their job.

Comment: @Shilly great advice. thanks everyone, should I delete this question or can a mod close it or something?